# Output being written to process.stdout twice

Tags: node.js, chrome-native-messaging

I want to pass a message from a nodejs script to chrome extension using nativeMessaging and thus am using the [chrome-native-messaging node module](https://github.com/jdiamond/chrome-native-messaging) in the following way to pass a message to stdout.

```
 var rs = new stream.Transform({objectMode: true});
    var msg = {"message":"pingfromelectron"};
    rs.push(msg);
    rs.pipe(output).pipe(process.stdout);
```

However, this is writing the output twice to stdout as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image: Screen grab of output]

I am not quite sure why this is happening. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: What is the `output` stream?

Comment: The output stream is from the chrome-native-messaging module which transforms a javascript object to bytes as per the requirements of chrome native messaging.

Comment: Did you check that that stream isn't duplicating output by temporarily removing the `.pipe(process.stdout)` and just attaching a `data` event handler to the `output` stream?

Comment: I am not quite sure how to do that..  The code for the output stream can be seen at https://github.com/jdiamond/chrome-native-messaging/blob/master/index.js  I do not see a data event handler attached, so not sure what do you mean. When I just use the example where I read the input from stdin and then pipe it process it and output it as stdout it works. However, when I want to just out a json based on a trigger that is when I get this output.

Comment: No I mean to eliminate `.pipe(process.stdout)` as the source of the problem you would remove that part and add your own `data` event handler to `output` and see if it's still duplicated. If it is, then remove the `.pipe(output)` and add a `data` event handler to `rs` and see if the duplication still exists there.

Comment: Removing the .pipe(proces.stdout) works now. I must've changed something because earlier using just .pipe(output) was throwing an exception. I can't remember what was the exception but I adding .pipe(process.stdout) prevented that! Well thank you for pointing in the right direction.